# import mysql.connector ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

In my program, I use `import mysql.connector`, but it doesn't work.
I saw other similar issues but they didn't help.
When I try to import in the python interpreter(version: 3.9.6) it works but when I use it in a code it is not.

Comment: Then your code is likely using a different interpreter. How are you running it?

Comment: I tried to run it in VS Code: python 3.10.0 64-bit didn't work.
CMD: python db_handler.py/db_handler.py - didn't work

Comment: Right - isn't it quite enough clue that your "Python interpreter" is 3.9.6, but what VSCode is using is 3.10.0? :-)  See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments ...

Comment: I changed the interpreter to 3.9.6 and still, doesn't work :( I'll read the link and hope to find the answer there.

Comment: I created a venv using ```python -m venv .venv``` and it solved the problem in VS Code.
But in the CMD it still doesn't work, but I think it is enough, tnx.

Comment: In the command prompt, you'll need to activate the venv (`.venv\scripts\activate.bat`).

Comment: I tried right now, didn't work. Thanks for trying to help :)

Comment: Stop using "didn't/doesn't/won't work" as a description. Its really meaningless to anyone wanting to help. Always replace this text with the actual error/behaviour observed. Including text test and observerations by editing your question is the ideal way to get to a solution. Your title is a good start, but question fails to show how you even installed mysql connector or its version or the environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

windows:

```
python -m pip install mysql-connector-python
```

Linux (Debian):

```
sudo -m pip install mysql-connector-python
```

python code:

```
import mysql.connector as mysql
mysql.connect(host="server-ip-here", user="mysql-username-here", password="mysql-password-here", database="database-name-here")
```

Comment: I used that command while using the .venv in the cmd and it worked. tnx