# importing mysql connector for python in visual studio code

Tags: python, mysql-connector-python

I want to import mysql connector for python in visual studio code but it is giving error like this :

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql.connnector'

what should I do??

I am tring to getting the python connnectivity for that ,I want know answer of this quetion .

Comment: Please research your error before posting in accordance with [ask]. In the interest of content quality, duplicative questions aren’t permitted here. Duplicate of [import mysql.connector ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69774415/import-mysql-connector-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install it first through PIP.

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

Then you can use this in your code

```
from mysql.connector
```

Find more here:

https://pypi.org/project/mysql-connector-python/

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-introduction.html